# Cannot properly define an rgb color

Tags: color

I am trying to define an rgb color. More specifically I want to create this color

[image]

which in `rgb` mode it's `(98,190,177)`.

I tried to define this color using the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \definecolor{tank}{rgb}{0.098,0.190,0.177}
 %\definecolor{tank}{rgb}{98,190,177}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (tank) at (0,0);
  \draw[red, fill=tank] (-2,0.5)--(-0.5,1)--(0.5,1)--(2,0.5)--(2,-0.5)--(0.5,-1)--(-0.5,-1)--(-2,-0.5)--cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the output is totally different from what I am trying to achieve

[image]

I also tried to use `\definecolor{tank}{rgb}{98,190,177}` but I get no color at all. How to properly define an rgb color?

Comment: You want `\definecolor{tank}{RGB}{98,190,177}`, note the uppercase.

Comment: or `rgb`, but with proper scaling of your values, dividing by `255`, rather than `1000` as you did in your MWE.

Comment: @egreg: Wow!!! Thank you very much! I didn't know about that!Would you mind posting an answer? Thank's again!

Comment: @greyshade : Thank you very much! I didn't know about that either! Why 255?

Comment: @Thanos see my answer - `255` is the maximum representable by one byte which is what `RGB` allocates to represent each base colour's value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colors in the screenshot are specified as

- HSV: (172, 48, 75) ∈ [0..360] × [0..100]<sup>2</sup>
- RGB: (98, 190, 177) ∈ [0..255]<sup>3</sup> (three bytes)
- HTML: 0x62beb1 ∈ [0x0..0xFFFFFF] (three bytes also RGB values)

Package `xcolor` supports RGB and HTML directly and HSV is indirectly supported via Hsb, where the saturation and brightness are given in range [0..1].

Package `color` only supports the basic color models such as `rgb`:

- rgb: (98/255, 190/255, 177/255) ∈ [0..1]<sup>3</sup> (three bytes)

Because of the different range, the values needs to be calculated first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{A}{Hsb}{172,.48,.75}% xcolor
\definecolor{B}{RGB}{98,190,177}% xcolor
\definecolor{C}{HTML}{62BEB1}% xcolor
\definecolor{D}{rgb}{.3843,.7451,.6941}% color, xcolor
% (r, g, b) = (R/255, G/255, B/255)

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\rule{10mm}{10mm}}%
}
\test{A}
\test{B}
\test{C}
\test{D}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

In RGB mode colours are defined by one byte for each of the colours red, green and blue - hence RGB. The maximum mavlue representable by a byte (i.e. eight bit) is `2^8 - 1 = 255`.

Specifying RGB colours may be done in two ways:

```
\definecolor{tank}{RGB}{98,190,177}
\definecolor{tank}{rgb}{0.3843,0.7451,0.6941}
```

where the first (with uppercase `RGB` in the definition) specifies the value of the colour byte, while the second (with lowercase `rgb`) specifies a percentage - i.e. the value used in the first divided by the maximum value `255`.